# Heroku deployment error H10 (App crashed) for Jekyll site

Tags: heroku, jekyll, rack, jekyll-extensions

I have a Jekyll site and I added a [plugin](https://github.com/jhshi/octopress-page-view) for Google Analytics page views to it. Everything works fine on my local computer, but when I deploy it to Heroku the app crashes.

Can anyone please help me with these Heroku logs and tell where the problem is?

```
Malahovas-MacBook-Pro:iloveip Svetlana$ heroku logs
Your version of git is 1.8.5.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
2015-08-14T05:24:14.535829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-14T05:24:17.629737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 39984`
2015-08-14T05:24:19.842915+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094554+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:88:in `rescue in load_key': Invalid keyfile or passphrase (ArgumentError)
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094558+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:80:in `load_key'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094559+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:34:in `load_from_pkcs12'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094560+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:25:in `generate'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094561+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:280:in `block in generate'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094562+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `each'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094563+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `generate'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094564+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:50:in `process'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094566+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-93ee931eadff/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:29:in `initialize'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094567+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `new'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094568+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094569+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094570+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094571+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094572+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094573+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094574+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094575+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094576+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094577+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094579+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094578+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094581+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094580+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094582+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.094583+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2015-08-14T05:24:20.794440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-14T05:24:20.781458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-14T10:53:47.441599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=57786964-0748-4da9-b1f6-b56a424328f0 fwd="176.77.46.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T10:55:47.896168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=e4927b45-853b-4025-928f-33e14d7131c1 fwd="176.77.46.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T10:55:50.016994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=af209d38-2abb-46a9-b11b-cd96ad661f0b fwd="176.77.46.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T10:56:35.572263+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-14T10:56:35.572288+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-14T10:56:35.528470+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0f800ff by jupiteror1@yahoo.com
2015-08-14T10:56:35.528470+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v20 created by jupiteror1@yahoo.com
2015-08-14T10:56:35.649203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-14T10:56:39.153642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 7713`
2015-08-14T10:56:41.421103+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725796+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `each'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725785+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:80:in `load_key'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725788+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:34:in `load_from_pkcs12'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725778+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:88:in `rescue in load_key': Invalid keyfile or passphrase (ArgumentError)
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725789+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:25:in `generate'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725797+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `generate'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725794+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:280:in `block in generate'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725801+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:50:in `process'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725805+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `new'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725812+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725803+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-93ee931eadff/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:29:in `initialize'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725818+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725814+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725817+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725824+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725826+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725828+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725831+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725833+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725839+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725841+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725843+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725847+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725845+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725851+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2015-08-14T10:56:41.725852+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2015-08-14T10:56:42.498111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-14T10:56:42.499051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-08-14T10:56:42.485760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-14T10:56:45.537126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 56309`
2015-08-14T10:56:48.851205+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181644+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:80:in `load_key'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181637+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:88:in `rescue in load_key': Invalid keyfile or passphrase (ArgumentError)
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client/auth/key_utils.rb:34:in `load_from_pkcs12'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181649+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:280:in `block in generate'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181648+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:25:in `generate'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181653+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `each'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181654+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `generate'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181655+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:50:in `process'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181658+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-93ee931eadff/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:29:in `initialize'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181659+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `new'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181662+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181664+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181702+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181704+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181706+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181705+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181707+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181709+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181710+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181713+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181715+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181716+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181718+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181717+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181719+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2015-08-14T10:56:49.181721+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2015-08-14T10:56:50.064851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-14T10:56:50.045855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-14T10:58:03.869075+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=f6dffc73-1c90-4ca6-b81a-99fa0ca21c4d fwd="176.77.46.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I added the name of the private key file for Google Analytics API to the `.gitignore` file and to the exclude list in `_config.yml` and it caused the app to crash when deploying to Heroku.